# How to deploy node.js app to heroku if the URL is dynamic

Tags: json, node.js, heroku

I currently have an node.js app running on my localhost:3000/movies/hulk.
Where hulk can be replaced with any word and will run my code and return a JSON object.

When I deployed this app to heroku, I received the URL

https://calm-sierra-94596.herokuapp.com

however, it doesn't work. When I try to do https://calm-sierra-94596.herokuapp.com/movies/hulk, it still doesn't work. I'm not sure how to fix this because I don't know what route to enter.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Such as the framework you are using and so. Also, you can run `heroku logs` from your command prompt to see deployment issues

Comment: 2017-02-12T03:27:43.599330+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/movies/hulk" host=calm-sierra-94596.herokuapp.com request_id=1219bf5d-caa3-4ffd-85ab-5d30d0cfc513 fwd="134.71.249.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-12T03:27:43.931637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-sierra-94596.herokuapp.com request_id=1d22b3c7-8d2b-4145-8b14-cc4c43db798e fwd="134.71.249.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: my first error is like this, and I have a procfile where it says web: node app.js

Comment: I am currently using express, cors, body parser

Comment: I just clicked that link and it seems to be working. Did you find a solution?

Comment: There could be many reasons on why it crashes in that route, check that all your dependencies are getting properly installed (also check your `package.json`) and that you are properly handling the request and sending a response

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the dynamic parameter in the route properly, and ensure you check the value before performing on it?

```
app.get('/movies/:character', function(req, res){
  if (!req.params.character) res.status('400').send('must provide character');
  // do stuff
  res.send('your stuff');
});
```